# Jquery - Using grep to search all columns of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive started learning Jquery and im trying to search all the columns of a table called questions. At the moment it only searches the column "q_text", however I would like to extend this for it to check q_options_1, q_options_2, q_options_3 and q_options_4. Ive tried using the || operator, but im not sure Im putting it in the right place.

Here is the code in question:

```
    //Adding the search functionality to our search button
    $('#search').on('click', findMatches);

    function findMatches(criteria){

    $("#questions tbody tr").remove(); 

    //Get the JSON data from our HTML and convert it to a JavaScript object
    //In the real world, this data will likely be retrieved  from the server via an AJAX request
    var questions = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('questions-json').innerHTML);

var results = $.grep(questions, function(x, i){
var index = x.q_text.indexOf($('#searchText').val()) 
return (index >= 0);

})

console.log(results);

 //Loop through the list array and create a table row for each item.
$.each(results, function(i, question) {
 var tblRow = '<tr>' +
'<td>' + question.id + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_text + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_options_1 + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_options_2 + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_options_3 + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_options_4 + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_correct_option + '</td>' +
'<td>' + question.q_difficulty_level + '</td>' +
'</tr>'
//Add our table row to the 'questions' <table>
$(tblRow).appendTo('#questions tbody');
});
}
```

Comment: what is actually happening and what does `results` look like? Also provide sample of what `questions` looks like. A demo in jsfiddle.net or other sandbox would help

Comment: This is what it looks like so far: http://imgur.com/lTm3EO6  Essentially it works, I just want to extend it so that the grep can search through the other fields as well, i.e if the user typed in "Dutch" into the search, the first entry would still appear.

Comment: then need to loop over all properties in object and test each value within `grep` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.each` to loop over object properties also inside your `grep` and test each one.

Suggest first of all caching the value for `$('#searchText').val()` so it doesn't require a dom search each iteration

```
var query = $('#searchText').val();
var results = $.grep(questions, function(x, i){
    var isMatch = false; 
     $.each(x, function(key, value){
        if( value.indexOf( query)>-1){
           isMatch = true;
           // break loop when match found
           return false;
        }
     });
     return isMatch;
});
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Caching the value is something I hadn't considered, was trying to figure out how to loop through the object properties, thanks again!